# How to send all the results from a lambda function in one email using aws sns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a lambda script that extract all the filenames in a bucket that were uploaded more than one hour before and send an email via sns. My lambda function works well. However instead of receiving one mail containing all the files, I receive one email for each file. This means that when I have 100 files found by the lambda, I receive 100 emails.
Is there a way to group all the files and just receive one email from sns ?

Here is my lambda sample script:

```py
import boto3
import json 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone 


def lambda_handler(event, context):
     AWS_REGION = "aws-region"
     sns_resource = boto3.resource('sns', region_name=AWS_REGION)
     TOPIC_ARN = 'sns_topic_arn'
     sns_topic = sns_resource.Topic(TOPIC_ARN)
     s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
     paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
     page_iterator = paginator.paginate(
        Bucket = 'bucket',
        Prefix = 'data/raw/mdf/'
    )
     
     for page in page_iterator:
         for object in page['Contents']:
             if object['LastModified'] < datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) - timedelta(hours=2):             
                 message =  object['Key']
                 
             sns_topic.publish(Message=message)
```

any help is welcome

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to get a message for every file found, you should not publish a message for every iteration in your `for` loop.

So the following line should be *outside* of the `for` loop:

```py
sns_topic.publish(Message=message)
```

Within the `for` loop you only create the message. After the `for` loop you publish it.

Example:

```py
keys = []

for page in page_iterator:
    for object in page['Contents']:
        if object['LastModified'] < datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) - timedelta(hours=2):             
            keys.append(object['Key'])
                
message = ",".join(keys)
sns_topic.publish(Message=message)
```

This will create a list of keys and then create a message that is just those keys separated by a comma (`,`).

You could create a message where every key is on a new line. This is up to you.

Beware: this does not scale. If you have thousands of files that have been created, the email won't help much.

You might be better off using [AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) and sending an email with a file as attachment. The file contains a list of new keys.